# Radio boxes and ajax / jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have radioboxes

```
<form method="post" id="myform">
        <label>A</label>
        <input type="radio" name="formtype" value = "1" checked="checked">
        <label>B</label>
        <input type="radio" name="formtype" value = "2">
        <label>C</label>
        <input type="radio" name="formtype" value = "3">
        <button type="submit"/>Submit</button>
        <div class = "space"></div>
        </form>
```

My ajax submission function is:

```
$.ajax(
        {
        data: 
            {
                type:  /////What do I put HERE <-------

            }, 
        url: 'in.php', 
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) 
            {
                $('#longurl').val(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
```

I am trying to pass in the value of the checked of the 3 radio boxes into something called type, I was wondering what should I put in the arrowed space above (/////What do I put HERE). I was trying to use $('#formtype').val() but it wasn't working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myform input[name="formtype"]:checked').val()
```

About the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

What you need to do is, find `input` elements that have the `name` attribute of `"formtype"`, then filter to only those that are selected (due to the nature of radioboxes, there will be at most one), then get value of that. The `#myform` is not strictly necessary, but it speeds things up a bit (because the browser does not need to hunt through the entire page to find the `name="formpage"` elements).

Comment: Thanks, though when I use "alert($('#myform input[name="formtype"]:checked').val());" it pops up saying undefined

Comment: Oh ty very much, it turned out that my form had a typo in its name >_<

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('#myform input[name="formtype"]:checked').val()
```